# Unable to upload managed package due to incorrect test coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'm trying to upload a beta version of a managed package I'm developing, but it fails saying the test coverage is only 74%.

But when I estimate the test coverage I've 91% both from 'Apex Classes' and from Developer Console.

Why do I see a difference here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured the reason was I had not included some of the test classes in the package. So considering what's in the package, my test coverage was less than the dev org test coverage.

Including those test classes in the package solved the issue.