# Code Coverage Error While Deploying

Tags: deployment, code-coverage

I want to deploy some of my classes (which are above 83% each) from sandbox to production. But it is showing code coverage error while deploying through change set.

There are other classes without test class in sandbox. By mistakenly I clicked run all tests in developer console. Is that the reason for showing code coverage error?

In my class, code coverage is showing like this[image]

But it should should show like this..[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the code coverage error? while deploying in Prod?

Comment: For all the negative markers, pls do explain as to why you are giving an negative vote as @salesforce 123 is a new contributor and some explanation could help him correct it in his next post

Comment: Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. As it stands, your question is quite vague. Please **[edit]** your question to be more specific about what you are deploying and what the results are. Screen shots may be used to good effect here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running all tests in Sandbox is not going to affect anything while deploying in production env.

When you deploy a changeset it runs all tests in the prod env and its got nothing to do with classes in Sandbox without test class.

you can restrict the running of all test classes while deploying by also specifying only a single or multiple test classes by choosing the Run specified tests radio button and giving comma seperated names of the test classes to run.

> Only the tests that you specify are run. Provide the names of test
> classes in a comma-separated list. Code coverage requirements differ
> from the default coverage requirements when using this level in
> production. The executed tests must cover the class or trigger in your
> change sets with a minimum of 75% code coverage. This coverage is
> computed for each class or trigger individually and is different from
> the overall coverage percentage.

[image]

Also take a look at the answers in the link below, there could be a pointer as to why your code is failing in prodn. [Can't get code coverage over 75% when deploying to production](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61203/cant-get-code-coverage-over-75-when-deploying-to-production?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, I selected run specified tests and gave 4 test class names. Again it is showing the same code coverage error ( but while testing those classes, it was showing 83, 86, 89, 90 respectively).

Comment: Are you using seeAllData= true in your test classes? Read through @drakored answer in the link provided in the answer. It should cover most of the scenarios why you are getting code coverage error

Comment: Also are you getting any other errors while deploying other than the code coverage errors? like a validation rule failing

Comment: BTW.. what percentage cover are you getting while deploying ? did you add your test class in the changeset?

Comment: How much % is getting covered? Are there any workflows or triggers running in prod and not running in SB or vice versa which could impact the data

Comment: A screenshot could help of your deployment and the error could help

Comment: Yes, there are some triggers and workflows active in sandbox. But we are not adding those to our change set. Is that make an impact on deployment? . I have another doubt.. after clicking the run test in test class and clicking on code coverage in main class. It is showing only all tests. code coverage is showing under tests tab - overall code coverage. Is that an issue?

Comment: can you show the screenshot of the deployment error? If there is a difference in the way your sandbox and prod are setup then your code would behave differently  in both scenarios

Comment: Thank you so much Prady...Finally deployed with run specified tests button.But why it throws error for selecting run local tests. Could you please explain me?

Comment: i can only think of other test classes using SeeAllData= true and the data in production is changed and is not satisfying the conditions in the test scenarios you have written which has caused few conditions not to be covered and hence reduction of coverage. Maybe you can run all test in production and see if the overall coverage is less than 75%. You can see which all classes have less than 75% coverage and check the associated test classes to see why they are not  fully covered